# event mapper of BLoC not executed, though debugging suggests it should 8-/

Tags: flutter, events, stream, mapping, bloc

That is a strange one, maybe one of you has an idea what happens:

I have some events for my bloc, the following one causes the issues (others not yet implemented):

```dart
@freezed
abstract class ProblemManagerEvent with _$ProblemManagerEvent {
  const factory ProblemManagerEvent.pmDataSyncRequested() = PmDataSyncRequested;
}
```

This should cause the bloc to emit a state

```dart
@injectable
class ProblemManagerBloc extends Bloc<ProblemManagerEvent, ProblemManagerState> {
  final IJournalsRepository journalsRepository;
  final IProblemsRepository problemsRepository;

  ProblemManagerBloc(this.journalsRepository, this.problemsRepository) : super(PmInitial());
  @override
  Stream<ProblemManagerState> mapEventToState(
    ProblemManagerEvent event,
  ) async* {
    print('before map $event');    // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    event.map(
      pmDataSyncRequested: (e) async* {
        print('in map $e');    // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        final Either<StorageFailure, Unit> response = await problemsRepository.syncProblems();
        response.fold (
          (f) async* {yield PmSyncFailed(f);},
          (s) async* {yield PmInitial();});
        print('yep');
        yield ProblemManagerState.initial();
      },
      pmClassProblemRequested: (e) async* {
        yield ProblemManagerState.initial(); //todo
      },
      pmRandomProblemRequested: (e) async* {
        yield ProblemManagerState.initial();  //todo
      }
    );
    print('post map');    // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
  }
}
```

This produces the following output

```dart
Restarted application in 4.549ms.
flutter: before map ProblemManagerEvent.pmDataSyncRequested()
flutter: post map
flutter: before map ProblemManagerEvent.pmDataSyncRequested()
flutter: post map
```

So even though it prints the correct event, the mapEventToState does not trigger the code associated to the event. Nevertheless it finishes the bloc's code and runs the event a second time for whatever reason (some rebuild for whatever reason). This is how the event is triggered, the following widgets are all rendered on the screen.

```dart
class ProblemPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final StackRouter router = context.router;
    return PlatformScaffold(
      appBar: PlatformAppBar(title: const Text('Home')),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            BlocBuilder<ProblemManagerBloc, ProblemManagerState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              context.read<ProblemManagerBloc>().add(PmDataSyncRequested());
              return Column (children:[
              Text('Hello world!'),
              TextButton(child:Text('los'),
                onPressed: () {print('home');
```

Comment: I think you should add `yield` before the `event.map(...)`.

Comment: Apologies, how could I miss that?! I looked. and tried and missed that all of the time. Actually it has to be yield*. Happy to accept it as an answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yield*` is missing before the `event.map(...)`. Now, it's basically the same as having a `void` function that does not return/yield anything.